# python 'environments have crashed'

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, openai-gym

I'm just getting started with using universe in python to learn how to make a game bot. I'm using a demo code to start with. However I get the same error after I run the code on PyCharm.

```
import gym
import universe

env = gym.make('flashgames.DuskDrive-v0')
env.configure(remotes="vnc://localhost:5900+15901")
observation_n = env.reset()

while True:
  action_n = [[('KeyEvent', 'ArrowUp', True)] for ob in observation_n]  
  observation_n, reward_n, done_n, info = env.step(action_n)
  env.render()
```

It would return,

```
raise error.Error('{}/{} environments have crashed! Most recent error: {}'.format(len(self.crashed), self.n, errors))
universe.error.Error: 1/1 environments have crashed! Most recent error: {'0': 'Rewarder session failed: Connection was refused by other side: 61: Connection refused.'}
```

I tried changing the localhost and I installed `golang libjpeg-turbo`, thinking that I was missing an installation. However nothing changed.

I'm using an anaconda environment, I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Have you fired up the server side [universe info](https://openai.com/blog/universe/) -- specifically the starting a runtime section --  `# -p 5900:5900 and -p 15900:15900 expose the VNC and WebSocket ports
# --privileged/--cap-add/--ipc=host needed to make Selenium work
$ docker run --privileged --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --ipc=host \
    -p 5900:5900 -p 15900:15900 quay.io/openai/universe.flashgames`

Comment: I installed docker which I was missing, and I put this line in the terminal, **git clone https://github.com/openai/universe && pip install -e universe**. I'm now getting, **from gym.benchmarks import scoring
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym.benchmarks'** when I run the code. When I put, **docker run --privileged --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --ipc=host \
    -p 5900:5900 -p 15900:15900 quay.io/openai/universe.flashgames** into the terminal as suggested in the link you provided for me, I get, **bash: docker: command not found**

Comment: For the second one you need to make sure that docker executable is in your path.  Kind of surprised it didn't install in /usr/bin or if it did that, that isn't in your path.  With regards to the first issue it looks like benchmarks has been removed [new gym removes benchmarks](https://github.com/openai/universe/issues/228)

Comment: I was able to correctly install docker this time. However when I run, `docker run --privileged --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --ipc=host \
    -p 5900:5900 -p 15900:15900 quay.io/openai/universe.flashgames` , It keeps repeating something along the line of,  `[2019-04-29 12:38:57,730] [INFO:universe.wrappers.logger] Stats for the past 5.02s: vnc_updates_ps=0.0 n=1 reaction_time=None observation_lag=None action_lag=None reward_ps=0.0 reward_total=0.0 vnc_bytes_ps[total]=0.0 vnc_pixels_ps[total]=0.0 reward_lag=None rewarder_message_lag=None fps=60.01` , I'm not sure what to make of this.

Comment: That looks like it is working and just needs a client to connect and give feedback.